# How to positioning the elements one under the other, regardless of the height of the item?

Tags: html, css

How to positioning the elements one under the other, regardless of the height    of the item? As having the following markup, to place the elements in the   following way:

[image: elemnts]

```css
.photo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_1"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_3"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_4"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_5"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should try [masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

1. Emulate this effect by using the css `column` property, I found [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/) for example, you can see how the elements are positioned.
2. Other way (most viable I think) is to use a plugin like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) as @kukkuz said before, it does almost everything you need.
3. Create your own grid using javascript and css in order to position every element based on other element's positions (which I wouldn't recommend) because you have to do some calcs and it could take some time.